# Accessing Redis server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I am not able to connect to my Redis server from remote AWS instance (both instances are in same VPC though)...

I have launched CentOS 6 instance and launched Redis server. I can confirm that server is running:

```
tcp        0      0 *:6379     *:*    LISTEN   891/redis-server *
tcp        0      0 *:6379     *:*    LISTEN   891/redis-server *
```

I have set AWS security group to be:

```
Custom TCP | port 6379 | 0.0.0.0/0
```

I am able to connect to the Redis server from the same instance using `redis-cli` but when I try to do it from some other AWS instance I get:

```
Could not connect to Redis at ec2-*.compute.amazonaws.com:6379: No route to host
```

Comment: The `bind` options in redis config is commented... What do you suggest I should put in order to support remote connections?

Comment: @ItamarHaber that's the exact opposite of the truth. 0.0.0.0 means that connections are accepted on all network interfaces.

Comment: @hobbs you're right of course - Oops.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using `127.0.0.1` IP for binding instead of `0.0.0.0`. Open your `/etc/redis.conf` and check `bind` option.

Comment: The bind option was commented, I have put the `bind 0.0.0.0`. Now `netstat` gives me column `Program name` with a bit different output: `1181/redis-server 0` . If you can check first comment on the question, Itamar is suggesting opposite? Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out firewall was on, so it wasn't possible to connect from outside. So to wrap it up:

1.Set Redis to allow remote connections by setting `bind 0.0.0.0` in `redis.conf`

2.Make sure the firewall is not preventing you to connect to your server. On AWS you can turn it off by:

```
sudo service iptables save
sudo service iptables stop
sudo chkconfig iptables off
```